# Computing a limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to compute (or prove that it doesn't exist!) the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \dfrac{y^4}{x^2+y^3}.$$

I think it should be easy, but I can not solve it! I think it exists; I've tried trajectories $y=kx$, $y=kx^2$, $x=ky^2$ and I always get $0$, so I think the limit is indeed $0$. Now I tried to use some inequalities but none of them seem to solve the problem ($ab\leq 1/2 (a^2+b^2)$, triangle,...).

Can anyone give me a hint on how to conclude?

Thank you!

Comment: No, not anyone can give you a hint on how to conclude. The person giving you a hint should have a good background in multivariate calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit.

(1). The trajectory on which $y=-(x^2)^{1/3}\ne 0$ has  a  $0$ in the denominator of the expression.

(2). Even if we avoid that trajectory, let $y_n=-n^{-1}$ for $n\in \mathbb N,$ and let $x_n=\sqrt  {|y_n^3 -y_n^4n^{-1}|}\;=\sqrt {n^{-3}+n^{-5}}\;.$ Then $y_n^4/(x_n^2+y_n^3)=-n.$ The idea is that for $y<0$ we can take $x$ such that $x^2+y^3$ is not zero but is as small as we like; in particular, much smaller than the numerator  $y^4.$

(3). For positive $x,y$ we have $0<y^4/(x^2+y^3)<y^4/y^3=y.$

Comment: Thank you! And +1 for the explanation on (2). Only one thing: I think you mean $|y_n^3+y_n^4 n^{-1}|$ inside the first root

Comment: In my A both terms inside the absolute value sign in the first root are negative...... But $y_n^3+y^4n^{-1}=-n^{-3}+n^{-5}.$ ... But I DID have a major typo: $y_n=-n^{-1}$ , not $y_n=+n^{-1}$. .. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On the contour described parametrically by $x=t$, $y=(t^3-t^2)^{1/3}$, we find $$\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^3}=\frac{(t^3-t^2)^{4/3}}{t^3}=\frac{(t-1)^{4/3}}{t^{1/3}}$$

And the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t-1)^{4/3}}{t^{1/3}}$ fails to exist.

Comment: Thank you! That is also a nice example!

Comment: @dlc You're welcome.  I hope this helps.  -Mark